# 0.0.0.0:PORT how and from where?

Tags: networking, network-programming, connection, localhost, netstat

I have quite a dilemma
there is an IP address on every machine, 0.0.0.0:0 also called "all available interfaces" IP

so my problem is like that - i need to map connections on local host using formatted output from netstat, how i should consider listning on 0*:0 or 0*:PORT? i mean:

what happen if S1 is listening on 0.0.0.0:1000, and S2 is listening on 192.168.0.1:1000?
will connection to S1 be intercepted by S2 (or inversely, S1 intercepted by S1)
i know that 0.0.0.0 is not endpoint for any connection, but consider that:

if S2 gets connected, do S1 hear packets directed on this address?

If s1 is listening on all interfaces:1000 including 192.168.1.0:1000 so where connection to 192.168.0.1:1000 will lead

thanks for all your answers!

Comment: The `0.0.0.0` address can only be for passive listening ports. Once a connection is made, that connection gets a local IP address from the interface the connection arrived on.

Comment: so if I am correct about this, I can't physically establish connection to address that listening on 0*:*, and via that address:port i can only announce that i want connection on one of physically existing interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

> what happen if S1 is listening on 0.0.0.0:1000, and S2 is listening on 192.168.0.1:1000?

The situation you describe is impossible. Whichever one came first will prevent the second from binding. The only way you can reuse a port in TCP is if both addresses are different *and* neither of them is 0.0.0.0.

[Windows excluded. Windows allows it, and if you can figure out what happens from the description in MSDN you're doing better than I am.]

Comment: thats the point, i am forced to write app both under win and linux so i need to consider both cases. There is no good documentation on that in MSDN and windows really allows to bind ports as situation above shows.

Comment: Looks like using [SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740621(v=vs.85).aspx) is the answer on Windows. Hard to see how MS got themselves into this pickle.